# FFMPEG: Remove packets based on PTS/DTS

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video which contains some audio packets beyond the end of the video data:

```
$> ffprobe -show_packets video.mp4
...
...
...
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=5653648
pts_time=235.568667
dts=5653648
dts_time=235.568667
duration=1001
duration_time=0.041708
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=1030
pos=25233684
flags=__
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=audio
stream_index=1
pts=11310080
pts_time=235.626667
dts=11310080
dts_time=235.626667
duration=1024
duration_time=0.021333
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=284
pos=25234714
flags=K_
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=audio
stream_index=1
pts=11311104
pts_time=235.648000
dts=11311104
dts_time=235.648000
duration=1024
duration_time=0.021333
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=285
pos=25234998
flags=K_
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=audio
stream_index=1
pts=11312128
pts_time=235.669333
dts=11312128
dts_time=235.669333
duration=992
duration_time=0.020667
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=290
pos=25235283
flags=K_
[/PACKET]
$>
```

The last video packet in the video has a PTS time of `235.568667` and a duration of `0.041708` - meaning all video data ends at `235.610375`. However there are audio packets ***beginning*** at `235.626667` and later.

Is there an easy way to strip these audio packets from the file so that the audio and video end simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slightly imprecise but generic way to do this is to set a muxer flag.

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy -fflags +shortest output
```

This may lead to one or two fewer packets in the longer stream than could be accommodated.

If you know the exact duration of the shortest stream, you can simply limit demuxing of further packets:

```
ffmpeg -t 235.62666 -i input -c copy output
```